# Storyboard: centre text horizontally in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uilabel

I know how to do it programmatically:

```
textLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

But isn't it possible to do that in storyboard? Unbelievable.
There is an appropriate property called "Content Mode: Center" in the attributes inspector, but seems it doesn't work.

Comment: There is a property called "Alignment" in the property inspector. Did you miss that?

Comment: @Sweeper No, I didn't miss that. I think it refers to alignment of the label in its container. Anyways, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it's indeed the solution. In "Alignment" I accidentally pressed "Justified" instead of "Center", so I didn't see any effect. Thank you very much. If you post your comment as an answer, I will be able to accept it. If you want, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sweeper has said in the comments. The `UILabel` has an `Alignment` property which you can find under the `Attributes Inspector` tab, set the value to `Center` represented by horizontally centred dashes.

[image: Text alignment]